# Rails model to handle composite records

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, inheritance, database-normalization

The first form of database normalisation is to hold potentially null fields in a second table, and join these in when they are referred to. The SQL would look something like this.

```
SELECT A.*, DA.* FROM ANIMALS A
INNER JOIN DOG_ATTRIBUTES DA ON DA.ANIMAL_ID = A.ID
```

This is pretty common for large databases to use, so only a dog would have the dog-specific attributes. Now I know this could be implemented as a has_one relationship, e.g.

```
class Dog < Animal
  has_one :dog_attribute
end
```

If it was a read-only model, I could implement the above SQL as a view, and just refer to the DOGS view in my Dog model.

Is there a way I can treat the composite Dog object (with attributes from the ANIMALS table and the DOG_ATTRIBUTES table) as a single model, placing attributes of both into forms, saving them as one command and retrieving the attributes of both?

Comment: Your query does not say what the `A` alias refers to.

Comment: Thanks for letting me know, I've updated it now.

Comment: Could you clarify your question? I cannot tell whether you want `Dog` to be a subclass of `Animal` (meaning, it accepts ALL animal methods/attr), or if you want it independent in the long run. Your current model says that you have a table `animals`, which holds a column `type` (one option being `dog`). From there, you have another model/table called `dog_attributes`.

Comment: The indention is to have a sub-class of animal which has some attributes which Animal does not, but to avoid adding further columns to the ANIMALS table. I would expect ANIMALS to have a type column.

Answer (score 1):

You're looking for *Multiple-Table Inheritance (MTI)*. Rails by default only supports single-table inheritance, but you can install [ActiveRecord::ActsAs](https://github.com/hzamani/active_record-acts_as) for this capability.

> Simulates multiple-table-inheritance (MTI) for ActiveRecord models. By
>   default, ActiveRecord only supports single-table inheritance (STI).
>   MTI gives you the benefits of STI but without having to place dozens
>   of empty fields into a single table.`